# Getting list of topics via JS Unified Api

Tags: javascript, push-notification, push-diffusion

I am trying to get the list of all the topics in my diffusion instance. I have multiple root topics, all of which have its own child topics. I just need to get whatever is on the server with its hierarchy. I've contacted diffusion support for this and they informed me there is no such method in the JS api. Is this doable at all?

I am on last build of diffusion 5.9 right now.

Comment: We'd like to assist Michael. Can you detail your use case a little?

Comment: @MartinCowie We are hosting multiple root topics which all have their own hierarchy. Most of the topics are single value topics. From my JS client, any time after I connect to the diffusion cluster, I first need to get the list of root topics and then respectively their children. The problem is, I will never know what topics are there as the topic names are generated by another source - this includes the root topic names as well. So I am looking into a solution how I can fetch these topics. I've fiddled with the JS files of the diffusion console (in deploy folder) but honestly got lost. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks Michael - we have some solutions and want to find the best fit. Please drop an email to support@pushtechnology.com and we can continue the conversation (via email and telephone) there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version v5.9 lacks an API to do enumerate topic trees, though future versions shall include one. The console uses an undocumented protocol and is subject to change.

The set of topics is rarely static, as topics are created and removed to reflect real-world events, so enumerating and subscribing to discrete topics is an uncommon practice. More often solution implementers will identify a topic branch of interest, and subscribe to that topic and all descendents using [a topic-selector](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.9.9/manual/html/designguide/data/publication/topic_selector_unified.html), e.g. Subscribing to `?foo//` identifies root topic `foo` and the set of both current and future descendent topics.

To your question about identifying root topics, we commonly see a number of approaches.

1. the root topics are baked into the client
2. the client requests the set of root topics, sending a request to a topic-path on which another client is listening.
3. Mostly commonly, the client does not actively subscribe to topics. Instead a control-client subscribes the client to the set of required topics, depending on the principal used during authentication. The control client becomes aware of the client's new session via a [session properties listener](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.9.9/java/com/pushtechnology/diffusion/client/features/control/clients/ClientControl.SessionPropertiesListener.html).